# how to determine sequence of logic evaluation

Tags: algorithm, sequence, evaluation

I don't if this question has ever asked before, and if yes, I'm really sorry for duplication.

I want to know if there is a algorithm to determine the right sequence of evaluation logic, for example using if or switch operator.

Like this:
if(a > b) then...
else if(a > b && b > c) then..

that sequence is not correct because if the first evaluation true than the second will never be evaluated. Therefore, Their position should be switched.

Any well known algorithm that can be the solution for this evaluation sequence problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I fear that there is no efficient algorithm for this because your problem includes the np-complete [boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). You can try to find a satisfiable order with brute-force.

Comment: This is part of Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE) It can be done by building a DAG on the (canonised) (sub)expressions. See also: Binary Decision Diagrams (BDD)

Comment: What _exactly_ is the problem being described here? What's the grammar and semantics of the expressions in the sequence, and what precisely defines "correct" and "not correct"? For example, should these conditions be swapped? `if (a > 0 && b > 0 && n > 2) then ... else if (a**n + b**n == c**n) then ...`. Note that if the first expression returns true, then the second never does, but a program that can reorder these would have to be able to know or prove Fermat's last theorem to do so.